# Python3 (Tkinter) - How can I use the "bind" method properly when you create a custom button starting from a tk.Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to create a new custom button using Tkinter, but it looks like more complicate as I aspected.

the idea behind my custom button is not so complicate. I just want a add a vertical line on the left side of teh button. when you click on the button, this line appears, and when you click on it again, that line disappears.

to do that, I created a new tk.Frame class. It contains both the line (a tk.Frame object) and the button (a tk.Button object). below the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class NewButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, text=None):
        super().__init__(container)

        self["background"]="white"

        self.button=tk.Button(self, background="white", borderwidth=0, relief="sunken", activebackground="white")
        self.highlight=tk.Frame(self, background="white", highlightthickness=0, width=4)

        if text != None:
            self.button.configure(text=text)
        
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.highlight.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsw", padx=(1,0))
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nswe", ipadx=8)
    
    def edit(self, wi=0, **kwargs):
        if wi==0:
            self.highlight.configure(kwargs)
            self.button.configure(kwargs)
        elif wi==1:
            self.highlight.configure(kwargs)
        elif wi==2:
            self.button.configure(kwargs)

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("400x300+100+100")
        self.parent.configure(bg="white")
        
        self.b1=NewButton(self.parent, text="Button")
        self.b1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.b1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.click) # it can't works..

        self.parent.mainloop()

    def click(self, event):
        event.widget.edit(wi=1, bg="green")

App=MainWindow()
```

the main question/issue is how can I interact with my custom button using `bind` method? I can't trig the `click` function because what I click, is not the frame (my new custom object) but the tk objects placed inside of it!

how can I solve this issue? how can I improve the code to create a real custom button? don't say to use `self.b1.highlight.bind` or `self.b1.button.bind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe the simplest solution is to inherit from `Button` rather than `Frame`. You can still use a `Frame` by creating custom `pack`, `place`, and/or `grid` methods that act on the frame rather than the button, then you can put the other widgets inside the frame.

For example, something like this might work:

```
class NewButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        # this frame will contain the button and other widgets
        self._frame = tk.Frame(parent)

        # initialize the button to be a child of the frame.
        super().__init__(self._frame, **kwargs)

        # define the other widgets and lay them all out in the frame
        self.highlight = tk.Frame(self._frame, background="white", highlightthickness=0, width=4)
        self.highlight.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # override these methods so when the caller uses them, it is the frame
        # that is positioned rather than the button.
        self.pack = self._frame.pack
        self.place = self._frame.place
        self.grid = self._frame.grid

    def edit(self, wi=0, **kwargs):
        if wi==0:
            self.highlight.configure(kwargs)
            self.configure(kwargs)
        elif wi==1:
            self.highlight.configure(kwargs)
        elif wi==2:
            self.configure(kwargs)
```

Notice how the button and highlight are packed in the frame (`pack` is simpler than `grid` in such a simple layout, which is why I chose it), and that calls to the `pack`, `place`, and `grid` methods of the widget are forwarded to the frame.

This won't quite work if you place the widget in a paned window or notebook, but since you aren't doing that and it's very rare to put a button directly in a paned window or notebook, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a self made object you will have to do this instead:

```
self.b1.button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.click)
```

For this to work you will also have to change your 'click' function to this:

```
event.widget.master.edit(wi=1, bg="green")
```

Comment: They don’t _have_ to do it that way. There are other possibilities.

Comment: Ofcourse, this is programming.

Comment: @JohnPapajim thanks for your reply but from my side your solution is a kind of workaround and not a really solution. what about if I click on the side where `self.b1.highlight` is placed? nothing! because the `bind` method, in your solution, is in use only on the `self.b1.button`. then I think that it makes the programming more complicated. I just wanna use my custom buttom exactly like it were a "real" tk button. in `MainWindow` I don't wanna think about the objects inside my custom buttom.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you write me the best practices to reach my goal please? as I wrote to Johon, in `MainWindow` I don't wanna think about the objects inside my custom buttom, I just wanna use the `bind` method like a normal tk button. from my point of view, the main changes must be done inside the `NewButton` class, but how exactly?